# Dirac propagator causality

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, propagator

I was studying the Dirac propagator and came across an excelent article which includes all the derivation, and interestingly we can conclude that the anticommutator is zero for space-like intervals.

The article is here: http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/classes/16f/diprop.pdf

However, in equation (10) in page 3, there's an unusual change of sign here:

$$\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3(2E_p)}(e^{-ip(x-y)}(\not p+m)+e^{+ip(x-y)}(\not p-m))$$

$$=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3(2E_p)}(e^{-ip(x-y)}(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{+}}\not\partial+m)+e^{+ip(x-y)}(\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{-}}\not\partial-m))$$

What I don't understand is the change of sign the $\not p$ of the second term when passing from the 1st to the 2nd line. It seems to come out of nowhere, and but I actually found that another article has a similar derivation (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/five.pdf, p. 113) and gets the same result.

Comment: Note the sign of $x$ in the exponential factors.

Comment: No, there's no integration by parts since we have no proper boundary conditions. Regarding the sign on the exponentials, the first term has $exp(-ip(x-y))$ and the second $+ip(x-y))$, and these remain the same in the 2nd line, so that's why I find it strange; I would've expected them to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivatives are acting on the exponential factors so you should reorder your terms and you left out the $\mathrm{i}$ prefactors. Note that: $$\mathrm{i} \not \partial \,e^{\pm \mathrm{i} p (x-y)} = \mp\, \not p  \,e^{\pm \mathrm{i} p (x-y)}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I worked out the algebra taking that into account and I got the expected result. I mark this as answered.